# Bokeh vbar Hover tool

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I have a multiple data bar graph and want to show the max value of each bar upon hover. I have already changed the code a couple of times, but never succeeded...
Here is the code :
'''

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource 
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool

modalites = ['0-510','511-1002', '1003-2167', '>2168'] 
valeur1 = list(tables.loc[0])                 
valeur2 = list(tables.loc[1])

valeur3 = list(tables_2.loc[0])                 
valeur4 = list(tables_2.loc[1])

source1 = ColumnDataSource({'x' : modalites, 'valeur 1' : valeur1, 'valeur 2' : valeur2})
source2 = ColumnDataSource({'x' : modalites, 'valeur 1' : valeur3, 'valeur 2' : valeur4})
p1 = figure(title ='Répartition des sinistres en fonction des surfaces', x_range = modalites, plot_width=600, plot_height=400)
p2 = figure(title ='Répartition des sinistres en fonction des surfaces', x_range = modalites, plot_width=600, plot_height=400)

from bokeh.transform import dodge
abscisses_1 = dodge(field_name = 'x',    
                    value = -0.25,        
                    range = p1.x_range)   
abscisses_2 = dodge(field_name = 'x',    
                        value = 0,        
                        range = p1.x_range)


p1.vbar(x = abscisses_1, top = 'valeur 1', width = 0.2, source = source1, color = 'green', legend = 'pas de sinistre')    
p1.vbar(x = abscisses_2, top = 'valeur 2', width = 0.2, source = source1, color = "red", legend = "sinistre")     
p1.legend.location = "top_left"       
p1.legend.orientation = "horizontal"  
p1.xgrid.grid_line_color = None       

p2.vbar(x = abscisses_1, top = 'valeur 1', width = 0.2, source = source2, color = 'green', legend = 'pas de sinistre')    
p2.vbar(x = abscisses_2, top = 'valeur 2', width = 0.2, source = source2, color = "red", legend = "sinistre")     
p2.legend.location = "top_right"       
p2.legend.orientation = "horizontal"  
p2.xgrid.grid_line_color = None       


tab1=Panel(child=p1, title='en %')
tab2=Panel(child=p2, title='en valeur absolue')
tabs=Tabs(tabs=[tab1, tab2]) 


 
h2 = HoverTool(tooltips = [( "nb bâtiments concernés:", "@top")]) 
p2.add_tools(h2) 
show(tabs)
```

'''
If it helps, here is list(tables_2.loc[0]):[2303, 2184, 1909, 1511]
and list(tables_2.loc[1]):[271, 418, 587, 1046]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of your code is in the line where you define your HoverTool. You are using `@top`, but in your ColumnDataSource `top` is not defiened.

```
h2 = HoverTool(tooltips = [( "nb bâtiments concernés:", "@top")])
```

If your want to use top as the maximum of `valeur1` and `valeur2` you may have to write something like this.

```
top = [max(v1,v2) for v1, v2 in zip(valeur3, valeur4)]
source2 = ColumnDataSource({'x' : modalites, 'valeur1' : valeur3, 'valeur2' : valeur4, 'top': top})
```

In this case `top` is well defiened and your code should work without changes.

By the way. You have defiened a HoverTool only for `p2`. If you need one on `p1` as well, you have to do similar things on `source1`.

**Output**
[image: Output Figure]